# Javascript populated by ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

I'm a bit simple when it comes to mixing languages and hoped somebody could advise me.

I have a page-turning magazine viewer, which is embedded on my webpage using Javascript like so:

```
<script type="textjavascript">

var attributes = { id: 'issuuViewer1' };

var params = {

allowfullscreen: 'true',

allowScriptAccess: 'always',

menu: 'false'

};

var flashvars = {

jsAPIClientDomain: 'issuu.com',

mode: 'embed',

layout: 'http%3A%2F%2Fskin.issuu.com%2Fv%2Flight%2Flayout.xml',

showFlipBtn: 'true',

documentId: '080311154822-183d3d8334a544518a0d5e324f2543d4',

docName: 'gan_issuu',

username: 'Jesper',

loadingInfoText: 'Greek%20Architecture',

et: '1251988902514',

er: '29'

};

swfobject.embedSWF("http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf", "myContent1", "420", "264", "9.0.0", "swfobject/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

What I would like to know, is can I populate some of these settings with ASP. So instead of line:

```
documentId: '080311154822-183d3d8334a544518a0d5e324f2543d4',
```

Can I have something like this incorporating ASP?

```
documentId: '<%=rs.Fields("documentID")%>',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be valid to populate a JavaScript object using ASP like this. See the recent question that was about doing this with PHP:

[Is it considered bad practice to have PHP in your JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607101/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript/8607257)

Comment: That's helpful thanks. So although it's possible and will work, it's considered bad practice. Is there a reason why do you know? I could probably put the necessary values in the querystring for JS to extract but ASP/DB is my preferred method...

Comment: No, it's not necessarily bad practice the way you're doing it. Because you seem to be constraining the JavaScript/ASP crossing to the initialization of a data structure, I think this is acceptable. If you had ASP floating around in random places in your JavaScript code, that would certainly be bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. HTML will be genrated on server side and then served to the browser for rendering.